# Google Pay payment sheet is opening in a new window/tab on Android Web instead of overlay

Tags: javascript, android, web, google-pay

As stated in the title, Google Pay isn't opening in an overlay but instead in a new window on Android Web (Chrome). I've more or less directly lifted the code from [Google's own demo](https://jsfiddle.net/34wxopb2/) that successfully opens in an overlay.

Could you help me identify what's causing the latter to trigger but not my own implementation?

```
function init() {
  window.googlePayClient = new window.google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
    environment: 'TEST',
    paymentDataCallbacks: {
      onPaymentAuthorized
    }
  });
  addGooglePayButton();
}

function baseRequest() {
  return {
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0
  }
}

function tokenizationSpecification() {
  return {
    type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
    parameters: {
      'gateway': 'example',
      'gatewayMerchantId': 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
    }
  };
}

function allowedCardNetworks() {
  return ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"];
}

function allowedCardAuthMethods() {
  return ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];
}

function baseCardPaymentMethod() {
  return {
    type: 'CARD',
    parameters: {
      allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods(),
      allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks()
    }
  }
}

function cardPaymentMethod() {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    baseCardPaymentMethod(),
    {
      tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification()
    }
  );
}

function getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest() {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    baseRequest(),
    {
      allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod()]
    }
  );
}

function getGooglePaymentDataRequest() {
  const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, baseRequest());
  paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod()];
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();
  paymentDataRequest.merchantInfo = {
    merchantId: 'exampeMerchantId',
    merchantName: 'exampeMerchantName'
  };
  paymentDataRequest.callbackIntents = ["PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"];
  return paymentDataRequest;
}

function getGooglePaymentsClient() {
  return window.googlePayClient;
}

function onPaymentAuthorized(paymentData) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    processPayment(paymentData)
      .then(function () {
        resolve({ transactionState: 'SUCCESS' });
      })
      .catch(function () {
        resolve({
          transactionState: 'ERROR',
          error: {
            intent: 'PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION',
            message: 'Insufficient funds, try again. Next attempt should work.',
            reason: 'PAYMENT_DATA_INVALID'
          }
        });
      });
  });
}

function onGooglePayLoaded() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest())
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.result) {
        addGooglePayButton();
      }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function addGooglePayButton() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  const googlePayButtonConfig = {
    buttonType: 'plain',
    buttonSizeMode: 'fill',
    onClick: onGooglePaymentButtonClicked
  }
  const button =
    paymentsClient.createButton(googlePayButtonConfig);
  document.getElementById('googlepay').appendChild(button);
}

function getGoogleTransactionInfo() {
  return {
    currencyCode: 'EUR',
    countryCode: 'FR',
    totalPriceStatus: "FINAL",
    totalPrice: '1'
  };
}

function onGooglePaymentButtonClicked() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();

  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest);
}

function processPayment(paymentData) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
      if (false) {
        reject(new Error('Every other attempt fails, next one should succeed'));
      } else {
        resolve({});
      }
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

Comment: did you put in the div and script in your own implementation?

Comment: Yes. One thing that could be the cause is that the code is ran programmatically with init(), instead of using onload in the script tag.

Comment: In that case, do `window.onload=init`

Comment: in a script in the <head> section of you HTML. It will run the function init() when the page loads.

Comment: @tealeoi could you create a reproducer on jsfiddle with your code?